# Format logs to add some lines only if there is an error

Tags: logs

I am doing a find to get some files like this and getting the output in a file and error to a different log file.

```
find /some_dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 > outputFile.txt 2>>log.txt;
```

There are other logs as well in `log.txt`. How can I append a few lines before and after the errors (like ***** to identify errors in find) and only if there are any errors in find command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `non_existent_dir` argument was added to `find` for the error message generation.

#### With variable

```
#!/bin/bash

error=$(find . non_existent_dir 2>&1 > output.txt)
if (($?)); then
     printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "message before" "$error" "message after" >> log.txt
fi
```

**Explanation:**

- `2>&1 > output.txt` - `stderr` (number 2) redirected to the `stdout` (number 1) and `stdout` to the `output.txt`.
- `$?` - the `find` command exit status. `find`  exits  with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.

#### Without variable

```
find . non_existent_dir 2>&1 > output.txt | 
  awk 'NR == 1 {print "start message"}
       {print}
       END {if(NR > 0) print "end message"}' >> log.txt
```

**Explanation:**

1. The `find` part is the same as in the previous variant.
2. `awk` part -  If input doesn't have any lines (no errors were happened), it wouldn't print anything.

   - `NR == 1 {print "start message"}` - if it is the first line, print the "start message".
   - `{print}` - just print all input lines.
   - `END {if(NR > 0) print "end message"}` - check at the end of execution, did it get any lines from input (`NR` - number of records)? If so, print the "end message".

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function something like:

```
function append()
{
if [[ -s /tmp/stderr ]]
then 
     {   echo -e '\nText you want like ***\n' >> log.txt
         cat /tmp/stderr >> log.txt;
         rm /tmp/stderr
     }
fi
}
```

Then run your command in following manner:

```
$ find /some_dir -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 > outputFile.txt 2>/tmp/stderr;
$ append
```